# How way i can do Two array use in a Loop

Tags: laravel

I have two array and i want to use it in a Loop How way i can do that

Controller Codes are:

```
public function showJobCategoryContent($id)
{
    $jobsInfoById = DB::table('jobs')->where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);

    $jobsInfoById = $jobsInfoById->map(function ($job) {
        return [
            'created_at' => Carbon::parse($job->created_at)->addDays(30)->toDateTimeString()
        ];
    });

    $dates = [];
    $dates[] = $jobsInfoById->pluck('created_at');
    $jobsInfosById = [];
    $jobsInfosById[] = DB::table('jobs')->where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);

    return view('front.category-content.job-category-content',[
        'jobsInfosById'=> $jobsInfosById,
        'dates'=>$dates
    ]);
}
```

How can I use this two array in a loop

My view page:

```
@php
    $arrayData = array_merge($jobsInfosById, $dates);
@endphp

@foreach($arrayData as $jobInfoById)
    <li>
        <h4>{{$jobInfoById->company_name}}</h4>
        <h5 class="deadline">Deadline:<b>{{ date('d F, Y', strtotime($jobInfoById->date)) }}</b></h5>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

It shows an error Undefined property:
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$company_name

{
$arrayData Value As Follows:

Array
(
    [0] => Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator Object
        (
            [total:protected] => 3
            [lastPage:protected] => 1
            [items:protected] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
                (
                    [items:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 3

```
                                [company_name] => Khulan Computer house

                                [published] => 1
                                [created_at] => 2017-10-22 15:25:54
                                [updated_at] => 2017-10-24 11:00:52
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 4

                                [company_name] => Khulan Computer house

                                [published] => 1
                                [created_at] => 2017-10-22 15:46:44
                                [updated_at] => 2017-10-24 11:00:41
                            )

                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 11

                                [company_name] => Computer Lab

                                [published] => 1
                                [created_at] => 2017-10-24 08:01:00
                                [updated_at] => 2017-10-24 10:53:57
                            )

                    )

            )

        [perPage:protected] => 3
        [currentPage:protected] => 1
        [path:protected] => http://localhost/jobs-zone/public/category-content/job-category-content/4
        [query:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [fragment:protected] => 
        [pageName:protected] => page
    )

[1] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2017-11-21 15:25:54
                [1] => 2017-11-21 15:46:44
                [2] => 2017-11-23 08:01:00
            )

    )
```

)[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]:

Comment: $arrayData = array_merge($jobsInfosById, $dates);
 print('<pre style="color:red;">');
 print_r($arrayData);
 print('</pre>');
 exit;


Please display output^

Comment: what the value of $arrayData  dd it

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd  and @ Gaurav Gupta  Please see the update of code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

Change your view code may be it returns array.

```
@foreach($arrayData as $jobInfoById)

    print('<pre style="color:red;">');
    print_r($jobInfoById);
    print('</pre>');
    exit;

    <li>
        <h4>{{$jobInfoById['company_name']}}</h4>
        <h5 class="deadline">Deadline:<b>{{ date('d F, Y', strtotime($jobInfoById->date)) }}</b></h5>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Undefined index: company_name

Comment: also how can i call this one <h5 class="deadline">Deadline:<b>{{ date('d F, Y', strtotime($jobInfoById->date)) }}</b></h5>

Comment: Please check my updated answer and display output of updated answer

Comment: please see the image then you can get a idea.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a array and atributing on element 0 of the array and you do 2 queries. So my idea:

```
public function showJobCategoryContent($id)
{
    $dates = DB::table('jobs')->select('created_at')->where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);

    $jobsInfosById = DB::table('jobs')->where('category_id', '=', $id)->where('published', '=', 1)->paginate(3);

    return view('front.category-content.job-category-content',[
        'jobsInfosById'=> $jobsInfosById,
        'dates' => $dates
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I am facing problem when i am using loop two array using one Loop i can not show my index it shows  
Undefined index: company_name